# Loop on dates within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem to create a loop on this data:

```
            TCT
03/02/2020  105
03/03/2020  68
03/16/2020  55
03/08/2020  37
03/10/2020  36
```

got by `high=df['Date'].value_counts().to_frame('TCT').head(5)`

I would like to see if for each date some words are included in my dataframe. To search the word I am doing as follows:

```
word=['mum','old man','children','family]
sub_df.apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(word))).any(1)]
```

where `sub_df` is defined as follows:

```
ref='03/02/2020'
sub_df=df[df['Date']==ref]
```

Example

```
Date               Tt
03/02/2020         indent code by 4 spaces ...
03/02/2020         backtick escapes
...
03/03/2020         add language identifier to highlight code
03/03/2020         create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~...
...
03/06/2020         to make links (use https whenever possible)
```

How could I include a loop on the above dates?

Comment: For starters, please provide a few rows of `sub_df`

Comment: Why not just set the `date column` as an index column, `df.set_index(....)`?

Comment: @Balaji Ambresh, I updated the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.set_index('date_column')

df.loc[ref].query(f'column == {value}')

# or 

def is_substr(row, value):
  if value in row:
    return row
  else:
    return None

df.loc[ref]['column'].apply(is_substr, args=['sub_string'])
```

Then use `df.isna().sum()` or `df.dropna()`

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1/2/2020']*3, 'col':['blah_1', 'blah_2', 'n32']})

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df.loc['1/2/2020']['col'].apply(is_substr, args=['2'])
```

---

```
date
1/2/2020      None
1/2/2020    blah_2
1/2/2020       n32
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @m-zayan. I have a question: since my sub dataset is made by a counter where I have no name for the date column,  what should I use in your code? Date should be those already selected in the groupby, i.e. those ones with highest frequency

Comment: If you mean, that you have already select sub_data date indices, then you can directly use `sub_data. apply(..... )` to check if specific substring contained in each row or not, then use `sub_data. dropna()` to remove rows which don't contain the desired substring, in case of you need to get dates with the highest frequency`numpy.unique(column, return_count=true)`.

Comment: Thank you @m-zayan. Since in the first table in the question the information (column's name) Date is missing, how can I recall it in your code?

Comment: you can rename it, but it's seems to me that date column, is already an index column, you could check `sub_df.index`, i.e. you can refer it `df.index`

Comment: sorry m-zayan. I think I have not fully understood how to proceed and which column to use :( why there is '1/2/2020' as reference date? I would need to automatically get information from the results of the groupby (if possible)

Comment: The `df.loc['1/2/2020']` is equivalent to `sub_df=df[df['Date']==ref]`  as the `ref= 1/2/2020` reference date, and I am using date column as an index column which more efficient, and what you actually need is to use `sub_df. apply(..)`, and all other functions are just complementary functions, so If you already have you own code to get  sub_df with highest frequency date, then you can ignore any of those functions ex. `.set_index(..)`,  but note that you need to use `.apply(..)` with a specific column `pd. Series`

Comment: I see. The problem I think is that I would like to avoid to use ref, since I would like to use some information directly from the groupby. I used ref since I was doing it manually, but in order to automate the process and build a function that can do it without looking at the reference date, I would need something that can link the two things. I think I should select the top date from the groupby as ref

Comment: In case of they use the date column as a ref or any other info, and set info column, say `info` as an index, I think I can't get your question, but if you are using groupby by a date column, then the output, still contains info about the date if you need to use it within a function, in case of this does not help could clarify by adding the second DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you m-zayan. I will try to figure it out and see what happens